# Is there a way to search text contained in linked documents in Enterprise Archietct?

Tags: enterprise-architect

Plenty of information is being stored in Enterprise Architect as linked documents. Is there a way to search content contained in these documents?

Answer (score 3):

In the GUI, the only way to do this is to open the document and search inside it, which I assume is not what you're after.

I don't think an in-EA SQL search would get this done either. The linked documents are in RTF, so you'd have to parse that to find the text you're looking for.

But you could do it with a script or an Add-In.

The Object Model API method `Element.GetLinkedDocument()` returns the RTF contents from an element's linked document. Then, you can use `Repository.GetFieldFromFormat()` and `Repository.GetFormatFromField()` to convert that to plain text.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be an open source version of such a script?